# Heroku endpoint

Tags: python, heroku

I wrote a simple HTTP listener and deployed it in a Heroku app.
I made sure to bind the port in `$PORT`.

Now, I've tried connecting to the app using the url `name-of-my-app.herokuapp.com:PORT` with 
and without port, but It doesn't seem like I'm getting through.

What address do I need to use to connect?

Thanks,

Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect to port 80 or 443 on

```
name-of-my-app.herokuapp.com
```

Heroku will take care of routing http and https traffic to the port assigned to your application.